# Expected Map[] but Found List[Map[]]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The scala program is iterating through a list of words and appending the word with value if already found or adding key->word otherwise. It is expected to produce Map[] but producing List[Map[]] instead.

```
    val hashmap:Map[List[(Char, Int)], List[String]]=Map()
    for (word <- dictionary) yield {
      val word_occ = wordOccurrences(word)
      hashmap + (if (hashmap.contains(word_occ)) (word_occ -> (hashmap(word_occ) ++ List(word))) else (word_occ -> List(word)))
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in this case you probably want to build the `Map` in a single pass rather than modifying a mutable `Map`:

```
val hashmap:Map[List[(Char, Int)], List[String]]=
  dictionary
    .map(x => (wordOccurrences(x), x))
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .map { case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2) }
```

In Scala 2.13 you can replace the last two lines with

```
    .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```

You can also use a `view` on the `dictionary` to avoid creating the intermediate list if performance is a significant issue.

Answer (score 3):

A `for` comprehension with a single `<-` generator de-sugars to a `map()` call on the original collection. And, as you'll recall, `map()` can change the elements of a collection, but it won't change the collection type itself.

So if `dictionary` is a `List` then what you end up with will be a `List`. The `yield` specifies what is to be the next element in the resulting `List`.

In your case the code is creating a new single-element `Map` for each element in the `dictionary`. Probably not what you want. I'd suggest you try using `foldLeft()`.